# Creating mobile controls for Javascript app (keyboard sim)

Tags: javascript, php, android, mobile

There's a game in Javascript which used the keyboard for controls to move the player. I'm wondering how you'd go about converting this to a mobile version.

I would need to allow the user to press graphic buttons on their phone to essentially simulate keyboard presses (and releases) and utilize multi-touch as well.

Any ideas on the best way to go about this? I have a few ideas, but I'd hate to start trying to implement one and find out it doesn't work.

Comment: You can't _neatly_ force the soft keyboard to remain open on a mobile with JS so the typical approach is to make specific on screen buttons for the actions that are taken vs. the entire keyboard

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm talking about. I don't want the keyboard open. I need to figure out the best way to create a graphic which gives you keyboard input. For example: round button graphics to simulate pressing the "Z" key on the keyboard

Comment: In which case it depends how the JS accepts the input (presumably via doc.onkeydown or similar). Then just trigger that via onmousedown of some button element.

Comment: SO is for [asking specific programming questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You should search and research **before** posting on SO.  See [Before You Ask](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#before).